# Building dynamic json using javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, ecmascript-5

I am building a dynamic json with the data coming from the server using angularjs. I have declared it as below. it only works if data from server has one item in the object array. How should i declare for it to work dynamically?

```js
$scope.items = [{
  id: “”,
  locations: [{
    name: “”
  }]
}]
```

```js
 for (var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++)
    {
     $scope.items[i].id = $scope.data[i].id;
        for(var j=0; j<$scope.data[i].locations.length; j++) {
             $scope.items[i].locations[j].name = $scope.data[i].locations[j].name;
        }
    }
```

This only works if there is one record coming from there server

Comment: Check - `$scope.data.length` and `$scope.items.length`

Comment: I am still looking for best answer on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use push() method in the for loop to add data into item.

```
for (var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++)
{
   //create a json object from your result.
   let obj = { id: $scope.data[i].id, locations: .....};
   $scope.items.push(obj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below

```
 var $scope.items = [];
    for (var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++)
    {
        var obj ={};
        obj.id = $scope.data[i].id;
        obj. locations = $scope.data[i].locations;// can assign locations array here.
        $scope.items.push(obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Actual  Problem is

$scope.data is already array with data that why you can access index i of it

where as $scope.items is array but still not indexed so Solution is
1. Use Push to add data
2.Firstly create index with json and then add data

```
$scope.items = [];
for (var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++)
{
    $scope.items[i]={id : $scope.data[i].id , locations:[]};
    for(var j=0; j<$scope.data[i].locations.length; j++) {
         $scope.items[i].push($scope.data[i].locations[j].name);
    }
}
console.log($scope.items);
```

Comment: Can you provide sample code as how you can achieve it?